# how to fetch coredata in widget

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I'm trying to fethch coredata in widget.

In viewcontroller, I succeed fetch coredata, but in widget.swift i can't get my core data.

here is my code

widget.swift

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        let containerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: <My GroupId>)!
        let storeURL = containerURL.appendingPathComponent("DataModel.sqlite")
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Entity")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
            } }
        
        var yourResult : [Entity]?

        let moc = CoreDataStack.shared.managedObjectContext
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", "test")
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "Entity")
        let result = try? moc.fetch(request)

        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "attribute1 == %@", "test")
                do {
                    yourResult = try context.fetch(request) as? [Entity]
                    completion(yourResult)
                } catch let error as NSError{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
        
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

the line
**yourResult = try context.fetch(request) as? [Entity]**

occurs error.

error is **Value of type 'Provider.Context' (aka 'TimelineProviderContext') has no member 'fetch'***

please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `context` is defined in function parameters, thus it is not a CoreData context, but a `TimelineProviderContext`  for the timeline.

Try fetch data with a following code as you do before adding a predicate:

```
yourResult = try moc.fetch(request) as? [Entity]
```